# What am I missing this? Do I need to use JOIN or UNION or a subquery?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get some practice making queries with SQL.

I'm working with a playground that uses SQLite.

There are two tables:`books_north` and `books_south`

Both have columns for: `id`, `title`, `author`, `genre` and `first_published`

The query I'm trying is to generate a report that lists the book titles from both locations and count the total number of books with the same title.

I can't work out how to even get started with the count.

So far I have

```
SELECT title
FROM   books_north
       INNER JOIN books_south
               ON books_north.title = books_south.title;
```

But it just says that `title` is an ambiguous column.

How do I do this? Thank you

Comment: it says title is an ambiguous column because after SELECT you just specified `title`, you should specify `books_north.title` or `books_south,title` depending on your requirement.

Comment: It is because both books_south and book_north tables have [title] column and as such, sql parser cannot determine which table's [title] column you are referring to, thus the error you see.

Comment: And your query woudl only ever give you the titles that are in both tables. Look up the definition of an inner join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `UNION ALL` to get the `count` of each `title`

```
Select Title,Count(1) as [Count]
From
(
SELECT title FROM books_north bn
union all
select title from books_south bs 
) A
Group by Title
```

Another approach using `FULL OUTER JOIN` (If your `RDBMS` supports)

```
SELECT COALESCE(bn.Title, bs.title) as title,
       ( bn.[count] + bs.[count] ) AS [Count]
FROM   (SELECT title,
               Count(1) AS [count]
        FROM   books_north
        GROUP  BY title) bn
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT title,
                               Count(1) AS [count]
                        FROM   books_south
                        GROUP  BY title) bs
                    ON bn.Title = bs.Title
```

Regarding your error message, Title column is present in the both the table so when you `select` the `Title` column you need to tell the compiler from which table you want to select `Title` column. It can be done by giving a alias name to the tables in `Join`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT a.title) AS TITLECount
FROM   books_north a
       INNER JOIN books_south b
               ON a.title = b.title;
```

A simple inner join would be sufficient to get your count. Use a table alias in `SELECT` to remove the ambiguity of column `title` as it is present in both the tables.

Answer (score 1):

In regard to the error that you mentioned:

The problem is `SELECT title` - it asks you to be specific about where `title` shall be read from, `books_north` or `books_south`.
So you need to tell either `SELECT book_north.title` or `SELECT book_south.title`, that's all there is regarding the *ambiguity error*.

The count is explained in the other answers. You need to learn `group by` if you want to display `title` and `count` (it is basically a `group by title` in your case.

```
SELECT books_north.title, count(books_north.title)
FROM   books_north
       INNER JOIN books_south
               ON books_north.title = books_south.title
GROUP BY books_north.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
   SELECT title, COUNT(title) count FROM 
   (
    SELECT title FROM books_north 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT title FROM books_south 
   )
   GROUP BY title;
```